# docker-compose volumes don't contain latest static code from image

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose, devops

In one container I have an HTML application with a compile step. I want to serve this over `nginx`. I don't care about mounting my local file system. All I want is to have nginx contain the latest version of the code after rebuilding everything.

But every time I `up` or `run` my `nginx` container, it contains a random old, out-of-date version of my static files! (both the compiled and uncompiled ones).

Here's what docker-compose looks like:

```
quickstart:
  build: ./services/quickstart
  volumes:
    - /var/www/html/quickstart

nginx:
  image: nginx:1.9.11
  volumes_from:
    - quickstart
  depends_on:
    - quickstart
  ports:
    - 80:80
```

And here is the Dockerfile in quickstart (simplified)

```
FROM codesimple/elm:0.16
WORKDIR /var/www/html/quickstart

# compile code
ADD ./ /var/www/html/quickstart/
RUN elm-make --yes Main.elm --output elm.js
```

I can't use a volume pointing to my local filesystem, because it won't have that `elm.js` file, which is created when the docker image is built.

When I browse quickstart, I see the latest files:

```
$ docker-compose run quickstart bash
> ls /var/www/html/quickstart
... index.html Main.elm elm.js ...
```

But when I browse nginx, I am missing elm.js, or containing an old version of index.html.

```
$ docker-compose run nginx bash
> ls /var/www/html/quickstart
... index.html Main.elm ...
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you getting a warning like "service is using volume from previous container"?

Comment: @warmoverflow No warnings. And it does clearly say it's recreating the quickstart container when I `up` the nginx service

Comment: @SeanClarkHess any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a volume for code because [Compose preserves volumes when recreating containers](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/#preserve-volume-data-when-containers-are-created). Code should change with the image. To fix it:

- `docker-compose rm` to remove the old containers
- Remove `volumes:` from the Compose file
- `docker-compose up`

If you make changes to the image, make sure to also `docker-compose build` before running `up`. In 1.7.0 (upcoming release) you'll be able to do `up --build`.

Comment: Thank you! This explains the craziness. Without volumes, how would you recommend that I link the static files from the quickstart container into the nginx container?

Comment: Because following your directions exactly, wouldn't that make it so the nginx container doesn't have /var/www/html/quickstart?

Comment: I think there would be an `ADD` or `COPY` in the `Dockerfile` to add them.

Comment: How do I ADD from another container though? QuickStart has its own dockerfile that adds all the files.

Comment: Oh, I see. If quickstart is only being used to generate the static site, I would probably run that separately, and `ADD` the files to an nginx container directly.

Comment: At the risk of wearing you out, could you demonstrate that? What does it mean to "run" a container that contains only static files? Also, I thought containers could only add files within their directory (nginx)? The files I need to add are in a totally different container (quickstart), and were created when the quickstart container was built.